# How to use referrer url in <b:if condition in blogger

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, blogger, referrer

I want to load some scripts only when traffic from a particular hostname.

For example:
I will load a script when blog traffic from [www.mywebsite2.com](http://www.mywebsite2.com). How can I do that? I tried a lot but still couldn't find anything related to that.

Here are some codes that I have tried.

```
<b:if cond='"referrer" == "www.mywebsite2.com"'>
     <script>...</script>
    <b:else/>
      <script>...</script>
    </b:if>
```

How can i use the referrer in that.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect if a link was opened from certain site if the link on that site does not have `rel="noopener"` value.

For example, your site domain is `http://0.example.com` and your referrer site domain is `http://1.example.com`.

In referrer site, a user was clicking a link:

```
<a href="http://0.example.com" target="_blank">link</a>
```

From your site, you could detect the incoming traffic this way:

```
if (window.opener && window.opener.location.hostname === '1.example.com') {
    // Run the script for `http://1.example.com`
}
```

To load external script under that conditional block, you could try AJAX or generic DOM insertion:

**Method 1:**

```
// Run the script for `http://1.example.com`
fetch('http://0.example.com/script.js').then(response => response.text()).then(text => {
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.textContent = text;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
    // Other script goes here ...
});
```

**Method 2:**

```
// Run the script for `http://1.example.com`
let script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://0.example.co./script.js';
document.head.appendChild(script);
script.addEventListener('load', e => {
    // Other script goes here ...
});
```

Comment: Thankyou it works. But again there is issue. If I want to load some external .js file then how can I do it with that if condition.